# Pass click function with input v-model params

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a btnSmall component with this props and click

```
  <v-btn
    class="white--text btn_main_product"
    color="red darken-1"
    @click="click"
  >
    <slot/>
  </v-btn>
```

```
  props: {
    click: Function
  }
```

I use this component like this in another component.

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="pa-4"
  >
   
    <v-text-field
      v-model="lname"
    ></v-text-field>
      <v-btn :click="clickAccept(lname)">accept/v-btn>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import BtnSmall from "../buttons/btnSmall";

export default {
  name: "editName",
  components: {BtnSmall},
  data() {
    return {
        lname: ''
    }
  },
  props: ['clickAccept']
}
</script>
```

and use this component in the page.
after use `<edit-name :click-accept="nameClickAccept"/>` whit this method.

```
    nameClickAccept(fname, lname) {
      console.log(lname)
    }
```

my method run with change text-field i cant use click.
i need run method with click on the btn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vue-approach would be to emit an event in the btnSmall component and react on that event in the parent component.. This: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names shows you how you can do it.